# Group by responsibles (multiple values) in list view

Tags: list-view, list-item, grouping

I have a very simple and very common task. I searched everywhere and haven't found a solution. Well I have a lists items. All these items have "people and groups" field with responsibles. One list item can have many responsibles in the same time. How can I group them in a list view?

what I see now:

```
user1,user2
-item1
-item2
user2,user3
-item3
```

what I want to see:

```
user1
-item1
-item2
-item3
user2
-item1
-item2
user3
-item3
```

Please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do it with out the of the box code as the People and Groups information is stored in one field, and the grouping is by one field.

You can not split that field with a Calculated Column Formula because Formulas can not not handle complex fields (like Person fields, Multiple choice columns)

On SP2013 you could write CSR (Client Side Rendering) code to create you own view... takes some JavaScript programming.

Or maybe a Workflow can help to split that complex Person/Group Column into multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks Danny, but can you explain this - "split that complex Person/Group Column into multiple columns". why would I need to split it and how to group multiple columns on same level then? can you give me more details?

Comment: It takes some(serious) JavaScript programming, persons are stored (like) "PersonA;#PersonB;#PersonC". You have to split that into individual values, Then keep record of each value. Once you have looped all ListItems you can display the info you want... again.. some serious JS programming

Comment: I guess we talking about **CSR** in the end. even if I split it, I will still need to have javascript code for looping and showing it in appropriate way. it frustrates that no one still tried it. I believe it is most needed list view and no solution from out of box or an example how to do it. but anyway, thanks Danny...